# New characters from old

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, character-theory

(All groups in the following discussion are assumed to be finite.)

Character induction is an operation that produces a character of a group given a character of a subgroup. I'm aware that there are other methods to get a character of a group from a given character of a subgroup, which aren't used as frequently as induction is (e.g. tensor induction, Suzuki's theory of exceptional characters).

**Questions:**

1. Has any attempt been made to formalize the notion of "deriving a character of a group from a given character of a subgroup"?
2. What are some other ways to get new characters from given characters?

Comment: For 2: surely tensor product deserves to be mentioned.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/a/448813/123673

Comment: Do [supercharacters](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.crma.2019.03.005) count?

Comment: It's often easy to modify characters of a given finite group $G$ to obtain new generalized characters ( using Brauer's characterization of characters, for example). However, showing when the resulting functions are actually characters is often difficult.